# how to deploy in heroku?

Tags: macos, heroku

I wan't deploy in heroku using ruby on rails. i try to commend "git push heroku master".
but receive error message. help me plz. i use Mac OS 10.9.

Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 430, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (371/371), done.
Writing objects: 100% (430/430), 852.48 KiB | 70.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 430 (delta 158), reused 139 (delta 25)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
/app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:88:in `block in ruby_version': There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue (LanguagePack::Helpers::BundlerWrapper::GemfileParseError)
Gemfile syntax error on line 68: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
$end
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
                   ^
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in`block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:76:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:80:in`ruby_version'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:180:in `block in ruby_version'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in`block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:173:in `ruby_version'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:259:in`block in install_ruby'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in`yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in`realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:258:in`install_ruby'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in`block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:83:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in`block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in`yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in`realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in`compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in`block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in`block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in`yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in`realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:47:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:43:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in`compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:124:in`log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:14:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in`call'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in`block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in`block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in`instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:10:in`'

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Comment: I'd solve. heroku create AppName --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git

Answer (score 1):

It says you have a parse error on the line
`gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

Should work if you write it this way:

```
group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku create AppName --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git